# Mocked function is `undefined` but unit test doesn't fail

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

In my unit test suite, I have the following mock:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
        NativeModules.MyModule = {
            myMethod: jest.fn()
        };
     })
```

And this unit test that uses it:

```
 it('has some functionality', () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(NativeModules.MyModule.myMethod));
    expect(NativeModules.MyModule.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

The `console.log` function prints `undefined` but the test passes.

However, if I add this line:

```
expect(undefined).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

The test will fail with this message:

```
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledTimes()

jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received: undefined
```

So how can the unit test pass if `NativeModules.MyModule.myMethod` is `undefined`?

Comment: One cannot `JSON.stringify` a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

> If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion
>   it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to
>   null (when it is found in an array). **JSON.stringify can also just
>   return undefined when passing in "pure" values like
>   JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).**

If you log the mocked function directly (`console.log(NativeModules.MyModule.myMethod`) instead of logging
`console.log(JSON.stringify(NativeModules.MyModule.myMethod))` you should see the output you expect.

For example:

```js
console.log(() => {})
console.log(JSON.stringify(() => {}))
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to `JSON.stringify` which would print those objects?

Comment: @octavian, what output would you like to see? You could potentially use [Function.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString): `console.log(fn.toString())` if the above didn't give you the desired output (e.g. in REPL)